# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'Pa' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Hi I am receiving this error in Google Play Music which is causing elements on the page such as hitting the play button or switching songs to become unresponsive. I have narrowed it down to recieving this error every time I click on an unresponsive part of the page. No clue what this could mean, any help? Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsIyf.jpg

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your second image, you can see that the error is thrown in `E.BI`

And first image shows that `E.BI` contains:

```
b=this.Re().Pa().Xb()
```

The problem is that method `Re` of `this` returns `undefined`. And, since `undefined` has no properties, attempting to call its method `Pa` produces an error.

Comment: No, because I don't use Google Play Music.

Comment: Ok, well thanks anyways. Would you know if it is a problem on their end or mine though?

Comment: Sorry, but I would need to know exactly in which situation the error was produced, the full source of those JS files (before obfuscating), and some knowledge about Google Play Music in order to answer that.